# Notification of Comments to "post authors" : ambiguous advice in 'Help'

Tags: feature-request

I recently left a **Comment** below an **Answer** to a post ([here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/493460/why-do-we-use-in-in-the-phrase-in-front-of/493476?noredirect=1#comment1191872_493476) - altho' the actual comment & post are irrelevant to the issue raised here).

The comment was intended for the **author of the original Question**. I did *not include* the name of the original questioner in my comment because I thought that the original questioner would automatically be notified of the comment. I have subsequently learnt that that is not the case, and that only the author of the **Answer** immediately above the comment would be auto-notified of the comment.

I am not questioning that practice, but it seems to me that the 'Help' information for a Comment is ambiguous.

The 'Help' drop-down for a Comment reads as follows:

[image]

And I did actually read that advice when choosing whether expressly to notify the original Questioner in my comment - but, clearly, I misunderstood it!

I found the statement that

> "The post *author* will always be notified of your comment."

to be slightly ambiguous: did that refer to the author of the original Question and/or to the author of the respective Answer, under which the comment was being made?

But I felt that the next sentence:

> "To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name"

clarified that ambiguity and clearly indicated that I needed to mention a name *only* if my comment was intended for a previous commenter: **not** if it was intended for the author of the original question or the author of the respective Answer.

I now, of course, know that I was wrong!  **But may I suggest that the wording of the 'Help' drop-down for a Comment should be clarified.**

- "**post *author***" in obviously unclear: I assumed that "**post**" referred to the ***entire Question***
- the need to "mention [a] user name" *only* for "a previous **commenter**" adds to that ambiguity.

*Possible* re-wording suggestions:

- "The **author of the Question or Answer immediately above** will always be notified of your comment."
- "To also notify a previous commenter **or the original Questioner (when your comment is below an answer),** mention their user name: ..."

Comment: "Post author" is the author of the post on which you are commenting. If you comment on an answer post, it's the author of that post. The only generic word is *post*; I think your first suggestion is even more ambiguous, because there is only ever one Question above your comment.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I realised that - in retrospect!  But it wasn't obvious to me - and may not be necessarily obvious to others who are not familiar with Stack Exchange - that the Qs & Answers were regarded as SEPARATE posts. I thought that "post" referred to the WHOLE item/page, inclusive of Q's & A's.  Please try to put yourself in the position of a 'newbie' to the system who is not necessarily familiar with the terminology. You say that the "only generic word is post" - but that's the problem: **the meaning of 'post' is not clear** to those not familiar with the system. ...

Comment: As regards my suggestions, they were *only suggestions* - but I was trying to convey that Questions and Answers are regarded as **separate** posts, which - as I've tried to explain - was not obvious to me!  Why should Q's & A's be referred to as separate posts, whereas Comments are not referred to as 'posts'?

Comment: P.S. to my first comment above: The sentence "I thought that "post" referred to the WHOLE item/page, ..." should read as "I *had previously* thought that "post" referred to the WHOLE item/page, ...".

Comment: Your second suggestion isn't even correct. You can't notify the question asker when commenting on an answer unless they've also commented on the answer. Saying that in the help information would be just wrong. As written it is correct.

Comment: @Catija Thank you for pointing that out. I was not aware of that, and that would explain why the 'Help' drop-down that I quoted above refers only to "a previous commenter" (which I had thought to be wrong).  This whole issue arose because someone had suggested to me (in the post I linked to at the top of my Q.) that one of my comments below the answer ought to have had the original questioner copied in - but now you're telling me that I couldn't have done that anyway! Thanks.

Comment: The OP had indeed [commented](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/493460/why-do-we-use-in-in-the-phrase-in-front-of/493476?noredirect=1#comment1191433_493476) underneath the answer of a different user. If you had pinged him in your comment, he would have received the notification. Unfortunately, I deleted my comments when  they were no longer needed, or so I thought, but my advice was correct.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Apologies - I hadn't remembered that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for sharing your experience.

As [Andrew Leach](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12115/notification-of-comments-to-post-authors-ambiguous-advice-in-help#comment52448_12115) notes, the site uses the word "post" as the hypernym of *question* and *answer*. However, as [you observe](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12115/notification-of-comments-to-post-authors-ambiguous-advice-in-help#comment52451_12115), this isn't necessarily obvious to new users.

However, I think what's needed isn't to change the term "post author" unless it's to something like "author of the post" to avoid implying some kind of pre/post semantics.

What's needed is a help page about "What is a Post?".

When I [searched the help pages](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=What%20is%20a%20Post%3F) for "What is a Post?", I didn't see any relevant explanation. The closest was the top link returned: "[What is a locked post?](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts)".

**My suggestion** is (for whoever can do this) to create a help page called "What is a Post?", define it appropriately with examples of question posts and answer posts, then link all instances of the word "post" to this newly-created help page.

Notes about how comments are treated, and why comments aren't posts, can be linked or textually included in that help page.